# Flash AS3 ReferenceError: Error #1056: Cannot create property font on flash.text.TextField

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, fonts

First let me warn you that I’m “old school” i.e. code is on my timeline and the only classes used were those automatically created when I added several new fonts to Script1.swf  which is my movieclip for embedded fonts.

On the first frame of my main movieclip which is named Round.fla, I have loaded Script1.swf that contains the fonts using the loader object.  I'm using a trace statement that shows that Script1_lb.swf is loaded.

I am using a listbox (script1_lb) with movieclip icons (jpg picture of the sample font) and the data is the name of the font class, like this:

```
script1_lb.dataProvider.addItem( {icon:akaDora_mc, data:"akaDora"} );
```

I want to apply the font to a text field (design_mc.info_txt)  that already exists on the stage so this is the code I used:

```
import flash.text.Font;
import flash.text.TextField;
var tff:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
var font:Font=new Font();

script1_lb.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,getFont);

function getFont(event:Event):void {
tff.font = script1_lb.selectedItem.data;
MovieClip(parent).design_mc.info_txt.embedFonts = true;
MovieClip(parent).design_mc.info_txt.setTextFormat(tff.font);
```

}

When trying to apply the font akaDora, this is the error I’m getting:

TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "akaDora" to flash.text.TextFormat.

I’ve been looking at this for hours and reading the help files but can’t seem to see what I might be missing.  Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it appears your trying to set the text format as your TextFormat object's font rather than the actual TextFormat, which the setTextFormat() method accepts as it's parameter:

you have this:

```
MovieClip(parent).design_mc.info_txt.setTextFormat(tff.font);
```

change it to this:

```
MovieClip(parent).design_mc.info_txt.setTextFormat(tff);
```

Comment: Thanks, I made the change and now the textfield disappears. Anywhere else I could check?

Comment: I searched StackOverflow and now see that I should change the above line to: MovieClip(parent).design_mc.info_txt.defaultTextFormat = tff; Is this correct, because now I don't get the error but the textfield still disappears.  thanks

Comment: The answer supplied by TheDarkIn was correct.  I changed the code as suggested again and then realized I missed:
    Font.registerFont(akaDora); in the Script1.swf that stores the fonts.
Thanks to TheDarkIn for taking the time to respond.